# How do I annotate areas of a report chart

Tags: layout, reporting-services

I've got a scatter chart in an SSRS report and a requiremetn to label each quadrant of the chart.

When I drop a text box with the label of each quadrant and get it to look just how I want it in the designer all seems well.

But when the report is run the flow based layout of the report put the text boxs vertically under need the scatter chart.

How do I get the text boxes to remain on top of the chart?

**In designer**
[image: designer]

**Rendered report**
[image: report]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding the Quadrant labels as a chart title instead of a textbox. You will need to enable the CustomPosition property of the chart title to True in order to place the titles in the corners.

I am unable to post an image without some "reputation" but I was able to add the quadrant titles successfully.